# get indexed element containing array from jtoken while getting response from currencycloud.com

Tags: json.net

I have the following JSON:

https://connect.currencycloud.com/documentation/api-docs/post-beneficiaries-create

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "payment_type": "regular",
      "iban": "^[0-9A-Z]{1,34}$",
      "bic_swift": "^[0-9A-Z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Z]{11}$",
      "beneficiary_entity_type": "individual"
    },
    {
      "payment_type": "regular",
      "iban": "^[0-9A-Z]{1,34}$",
      "bic_swift": "^[0-9A-Z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Z]{11}$",
      "beneficiary_entity_type": "company"
    },
    {
      "payment_type": "priority",
      "beneficiary_entity_type": "individual",
      "beneficiary_address": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_city": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_country": "^[A-z]{2}$",
      "beneficiary_first_name": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_last_name": "^.{1,255}",
      "iban": "^[0-9A-Z]{1,34}$",
      "bic_swift": "^[0-9A-Z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Z]{11}$"
    },
    {
      "payment_type": "priority",
      "beneficiary_entity_type": "company",
      "beneficiary_address": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_city": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_country": "^[A-z]{2}$",
      "beneficiary_company_name": "^.{1,255}",
      "iban": "^[0-9A-Z]{1,34}$",
      "bic_swift": "^[0-9A-Z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Z]{11}$"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve 3rd list from this array ..that is

```
    {
      "payment_type": "priority",
      "beneficiary_entity_type": "individual",
      "beneficiary_address": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_city": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_country": "^[A-z]{2}$",
      "beneficiary_first_name": "^.{1,255}",
      "beneficiary_last_name": "^.{1,255}",
      "iban": "^[0-9A-Z]{1,34}$",
      "bic_swift": "^[0-9A-Z]{8}$|^[0-9A-Z]{11}$"
    },
```

someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JToken.Load()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Load.htm) to load the JSON into memory, and then use [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) to query for an object in the JSON object hierarchy:

```
        var root = JToken.Parse(json);
        var item = root.SelectToken("details[2]");
```

Array indexing is zero-based.

**Update**

To select a specific property inside an object, e.g. `"payment_type"`, add the name of the property to the existing query, and cast to the expected type:

```
        var payment_type = (string)root.SelectToken("details[2].payment_type");
```

[`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) supports the JSONPath query syntax as specified here: [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Comment: Thanks a ton for help...but now i am with the issue to select perticular value say "payment_type": "priority", from this details[2] array??

Comment: hey if i want to have this response in for loop and want details[i] where from ith element i will be able to access everything..please help me for this

Comment: @Namrata - on stackoverflow the preferred format is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  I suggest asking another question.  Also, if this question is answered, consider [marking it as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).